Show with 12 members, like Power Rangers, who could form a giant robot when together
I watched a show that was very similar to the one mentioned in this link. It was just like Power Rangers but it's not one of them.
The show featured 12 members. There were three teams and each team had four members. Together they could form a giant robot.

This is Ultra Star God Gransazer (AKA Chouseishin Gransazer), a Japanese 'Tokusatsu' TV show intended to showcase a range of plastic crap high quality merchandise.
It was very much in the style of Power Rangers.

Some 400,000,000 years after an advanced human civilization was
destroyed by aliens, 12 direct descendants of the civilization's
warriors (called "Sazers") have their powers awakened and form four
tribes: Flame, Wind, Earth and Water. Each Sazer is based on a Zodiac
sign represented in an animal totem or spirit representation. At
first, they wage war on each other, but after learning the truth of
their ancestry and their reason for awakening, the Gransazer tribes
unite to protect Earth from the Warp Monarch, an alliance of various
alien species, from once again extinguishing all life on the planet.





If you liked this answer, don't forget to browse my range of 'Grand Answer God Valorum™' toys and collectables.

Watching that intro makes me wonder if they had the full range of toys ready to go before they had a plot

@Separatrix - Yes.

Four-hundred million years, eh? I'm here to tell you, that's a mighty long time.

I kind of like the whale plane.

This sounds very much like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltron
There were several versions of this series, one series used 3 teams of vehicles and drivers (land, sea and air)

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  According to the linked article, Vehicle Team Voltron had 3 teams of 5, for 15 members, not twelve as described in the question.  Can you add more details (and maybe some screencaps) and flesh this out to better argue for this?
